# (How) do the modifiable areal unit problem and modifiable temporal unit problem interact?

Tags: spatial-statistics, spatio-temporal-data, landscape

I am reconstructing historical time series of land use and other related data from a variety of sources with different spatial and temporal resolutions and would be interested in what possible (hidden) problems could arise when aggregating and combining the data.

I am especially curious about the ecological fallacy and whether choices in the aggregation of temporal data affect change of support in the spatial dimension and vice versa?

References to literature are fine, but I am more interested in examples of how those interactions would arise if at all.

Comment: I've read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7292/how-do-you-choose-a-unit-of-analysis-level-of-aggregation-in-a-time-series) on stats.se and I am familiar with the basics of spatial statistics, but haven't yet read too many actual research papers that deal with this issue.

Comment: I found a [blog entry](http://www.biomedware.com/blog/2011/it%E2%80%99s-about-space-and-time-from-the-modifiable-areal-unit-problem-maup-to-the-modifiable-temporal-unit-problem-mtup-to-the-modifiable-spatio-temporal-unit-problem-mstup/) and an [abstract](http://www.biogeosciences-discuss.net/8/8545/2011/bgd-8-8545-2011.html), but they don't quite answer the question on their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read Openshaw's (1984) and Cressie's (1996) papers? This is a good place to start.

Openshaw, S. (1984). The Modifiable Areal Unit Problem. CATMOG 38. Norwich: Geo Books. ISBN 0-86094-134-5. http://qmrg.org.uk/files/2008/11/38-maup-openshaw.pdf

Cressie, N. (1996) Change of Support and the Modifiable Areal Unit Problem. Geographical Systems, 3:159-180.

If you examine the primary literature you will realize that the Modifiable Areal Unit Problem is inherently temporal in nature. Ecological Fallacy arises when you attempt to draw inference across levels of organization.

Comment: I haven't got my hands on Cressie (1996) yet, but Openshaw does not directly discuss the statistical consequences of temporal aggregation and choice of time periods and whether they modify the effects of spatial grouping and zoning.

de Jong and de Bruin (2012) [doi:10.5194/bg-9-71-2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.5194/bg-9-71-2012) discuss temporal aggregation, but not in the context of MAUP.

Comment: This short paper by Cressie (1998) seems to be directly relevant: Aggregation and interaction issues in statistical modeling of spatiotemporal processes. *Geoderma*, 85: 133-140. [doi:10.1016/S0016-7061(98)00017-2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0016-7061(98)00017-2).

Comment: The link to the Openshaw paper is broken. As of 2022, this is a working one: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/iss/SGO9010/openshaw1983.pdf (the year in the file name is a typo)